# Where did the "this question will be eligible for bounty in X hours" button go?

Tags: bug, user-interface, bounty

I do not know if it *is* a bug, but I seem to remember a few months back there was some text saying  "this question will be eligible for bounty in X hours", but now I do not see it.

Why is it gone? Do I remember correctly that it was there earlier?

([this is the question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/210351/what-is-the-chance-of-rolling-at-least-10-before-a-1-on-a-d20), I want to reward Daniel R. Collins for his very short and logical answer)

Comment: What question are you trying to bounty?

Comment: I think this might only be shown on your own questions but not on others'.

Comment: @VLAZ, sorry, you are right, I failed to mention that it is my question.

Comment: Hmm, AFAIK it should show you. Unless this is a bug or some extra weird rules around the text. At any rate, if you're unsure - the bounty option should be available 48 hours after posting the question.

Comment: I wonder if it's because there is an accepted answer. TBH, I don't think it should make a difference but maybe the system counts it as "User probably doesn't want a bounty".

Comment: You remember correctly it was there earlier!

Comment: @VLAZ Yes, I saw a meta.se post earlier about how the message doesn’t show when you’ve accepted an answer already.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov turn this into an answer and I accept it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Accepting an answer removes the "question eligible for bounty in *x* hours/days" link from your question, though "Start a bounty" will appear once the question is eligible (at least 48 hours old). See [Why is the "question eligible for bounty in x hours/days" link not shown when you accepted an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/350183/323179)